# Concurrency in Java - Delegating tasks to worker threads, am I doing it right?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

So I'm making an emulator for an online game and I can't seem to think of a good way to deal with lots of tasks running simultaneously. Loading everything on a single thread just doesn't work, obviously.

My idea was to have a main thread that delegates tasks to x amount of worker threads. Once the main thread is done queueing tasks, it signals the workers to start firing tasks and halts untill they have finished. My implementation is as follows:

```
package com.rs2.engine;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.rs2.util.Timer;

public class Engine implements Runnable {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private int currentTick;
    private ArrayList<Task> tasks;
    private Timer timer;

    public Engine(int workers) {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workers);
        this.scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        this.currentTick = 0;
        this.tasks = new ArrayList<>(10000);
        this.timer = new Timer();
    }

    public int getCurrentTick() {
        return currentTick;
    }

    public ExecutorService getWorkers() {
        return executorService;
    }

    public void start() {
        this.scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0, 600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void cycle() {

    }

    public void queueTask(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    public void processQueuedTasks() {
        try {
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                Task t = tasks.get(i);
                t.setCountDownLatch(latch);
                executorService.submit(t);
            }
            latch.await();
            tasks.clear();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        timer.reset();
        cycle();
        currentTick++;
        //System.out.println("Cycle time: "+timer.elapsed());
    }

}
```

**queueTask()** and **processQueuedTasks()** are only called from the main thread. This Engine is used to deal with any and all tasks that the server needs executing. First it processes networking events (incoming packets), then updating entities and other events. That's why I like to keep it abstract.

Here's the Task class aswell:

```
package com.rs2.engine;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Task implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public Task() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        execute();
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public void execute() {

    }

    public void setCountDownLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. In the Engine class, is it OK to work with a regular ArrayList in terms of concurrency?
2. Is there a better way of queueing tasks to the ExecutorService? I feel like it might cause issues if too many tasks are queued to it at the same time.
3. Are there any engine frameworks I should be looking at before I start reinventing the wheel?

Comment: That probably belongs over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried that you might be queueing too much tasks in the `ExecutorService` you can use `Semaphore` to limit the tasks it can run at a time.

Put it in your `processQueuedTasks()` method for loop to limit the number of tasks to be run.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Semaphore` to throttle the number of tasks run concurrently, you could set the number of threads in the threadpool. You will only get as many tasks running concurrently as you have threads

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);`

`public void queueTask(Task task) {`
As this method is public, it can be called from any thread and so the `ArrayList` would not be thread safe.  Think about what would happen if you tried to queue a task during the time they are submitted to the executor.  You have 'borrowed' functionality from a thread pool executor and placed it in your code by having the collection for tasks.

Comment: That method only gets called from the main thread, so I'm not concerned about that. I just don't think ArrayList is what I should be using in this scenario.